# Can android content provider be used for simple data such as name:value pairs

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am writing a small featurecontrol-application, which has several feature settings stored and managed. All applications use my featurecontrol-application to retrieve settings like whether feature-x is enabled or not or what is feature-x-value . Can I use contentprovider for this or are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several applications, and they have to share same data (content) usage of ContentProvider looks to me as quite good and logical solution.

Content provider is one option to implement communication between different applications. But it does not need DB as a backbone. Instead of DB you can use table of constants. To create ContentProvider you just need to override several functions, no constraint is imposed to use DB.

Another option is to implement IPC via AIDL. That also gives you interface to share objects, but IMO since you just need to share constants ContentProvider is easier and faster solution.

Comment: What I need is more of a simple interface to be exported to the other applications like com.mydomain.featurecontroller.getFeatureValue(String featurename). If I use content provider, the applications need to unnecessarily use database related functions to decode the value. Is there any way of custom IPC in android, through which applications communicate in non-db way?

Comment: From the android documentation, It seems ContentResolver.query() is the only function to get the content other than file or resource, which returns a cursor(db-query result). This indicates that database kind of interface is mandatory while using ContentProvider for data other than file and android resource. Did I miss something here?

Comment: Cursor is generic way to deliver results of search, and may be created independent of  database.

Comment: what I want is to have clean interface, some readable API. Cursor is mainly to deal with a listing. If it has to be used for single value, it requires unnecessary looping through the rows and columns in the resultset of the query(). After doing google, it seems AIDL is what I am looking for.

Comment: Cursor does not define API. It just helpes to deliver results. API to applications sharing data is defined through clean and simple ContentProvider. AIDL is OK for IPC,, but if I understood you correctly you want to share constants, not objects.

Comment: Thanks.. Till now I was wondering how to add custom data into a SQLiteCursor. I think MatrixCursor can be used to return non-db data, where the rows can be added through functions provided in MatrixCursor.

Comment: Yes, MatrixCursor is what you need. Cheers.